# How to change CSS using Javascript in Moodle (mustache)?

Tags: jquery, moodle, mustache

Moodle allows to change CSS using mustache templates, for example I change background color of Moodle login by adding to  .../boost/template/login.mustache the below line:

```
$("#page").css('background-color','#e4002b');
```

The above works fine, but when I try to change color of footer it doesnt work, I add almost the line to footer.mustache

```
.... 
{{#js}}
    $(".foo").css('background-color','red !important');
   $(".foo").html('LOL');
{{/js}}
```

CSS does not apply,  BUT the content of the div DOES change to LOL, any idea what is happening:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below one works fine for me.

Use .attr() instead of .css()

```
{{#js}}
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    $("#page-footer").attr('style', 'background-color: red !important;');
})
{{/js}}
```